# Why is my csv splitting script returning extra rows before the header?

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file that I download periodically. The CSV expects to be split, so it is split up in chunks of 5000, including the header at the top of each split csv.

This means my header lines are at 1, 5001, 10002, 15003, 20004, etc...

I have written a php script to do the job of splitting the file, however I can't seem to capture the pattern to include the header ONLY at the header.

```
<?php 
$inputFile = 'import.csv';
$outputFile = 'output_';

$splitSize = 5000;

$in = fopen($inputFile, 'r');

$rowCount = 0;
$fileCount = 1;
while (!feof($in)) {
    if (($rowCount % $splitSize) == 0) {
        if ($rowCount > 0) {
            fclose($out);
        }
        $out = fopen($outputFile . $fileCount++ . '.csv', 'w');
    }
    $data = fgetcsv($in);
    var_dump($data);
    fputcsv($out, $data);
    $rowCount++;

}
}

fclose($out);
```

The problem here is that by the third file, I am getting an extra line of data at the top of each file which should have been printed into the previous file.

This would lead me to believe that I need my chunks to be 5001 lines in size instead, but if I provide 5001 as the splitsize parameter, I get the opposite.  The first file contains the header at line 1 and 5001.

I'd love to just split the file anywhere the header is detected, so if $data[0] is equal to 'Action', split the file, but I'm kind of lost at how to accomplish that as well.

Comment: *chunks of 5000, including the header* -> headers are at lines 1, 5001, 10001, 15001, 20001...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you would prefer to split if $data[0] == 'Action', this is what I would suggest:

```
while (!feof($in)) {
    $data = fgetcsv($in);

    if ($data[0] == 'Action') {
        if ($rowCount > 0) {
            fclose($out);
        }
        $out = fopen($outputFile . $fileCount++ . '.csv', 'w');
    }

    fputcsv($out, $data);
    $rowCount++;
}
```